# Pig - FilterFunc don't take the entire tuples

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, bigdata, apache-pig

I have a problem with one of my Pig's filterfuncs.

But first, I'll give you the context.

```
A = LOAD 'pig/hado/start_extrait2.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (DAT_START:chararray, COD_IPUSER:chararray, NDI_START:chararray);

hado_search_file = LOAD 'pig/hado/recherche_hado.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (DATE_HADO:chararray, IP_RECHERCHEE:chararray);

result2 = JOIN hado_search_file by IP_RECHERCHEE LEFT OUTER, A by COD_IPUSER;
```

Let's try to vizualize "result2" variable:

```
describe result2;

{hado_search_file::DATE_HADO: chararray,hado_search_file::IP_RECHERCHEE: chararray,A::COD_IPUSER: chararray,A::DAT_START: chararray,A::NDI_START: chararray}

dump result2;

(2014/03/10 00:00:00,192.168.2.67,,,)
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,2014/03/10 00:00:00,0385578168)
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,2014/03/10 00:00:00,0385578168)
(2014/03/10 00:00:01,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,2014/03/10 00:00:00,0385578168)
(2014/03/10 00:00:01,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,2014/03/10 00:00:00,0385578168)
```

Then, I try to use a FilterFunc

```
flt = FILTER result2 BY dateInferiorOrNull();
```

The begining of the code is:

```
public class dateInferiorOrNull  extends FilterFunc {

    @Override
    public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(input);

        ...

    }
}
```

I was expecting to have the same output than the "dump result2" I made before, but instead, i had something like this:

```
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88)
```

Only the two first fields have been taken !

When I try to display the tuple size, the programs says that the tuple's size is 2 !

So it seems like the filter func doesn't take the entire tuple as an input.

Why is that happening ?

Thnaks for your help.

Comment: Is that really the way you call your UDF? `flt = FILTER result2 BY dateInferiorOrNull();` ?

Comment: Try this `flt = FILTER result2 BY dateInferiorOrNull(*);`

Comment: This is it. I didn't put the * but I write the fields names instead. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

From the input tuple (you are passing as argument to the UDF) get the column which you want in your result then add it to the DataBag then return this DataBag from your UDF. Output of this UDF is a Bag then flatten this Bag in your pig script.